# Displaying a randomised set of image and text from a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-dictionary

I'm trying to retrieve and display from a dictionary a randomised set of an image with its associated text on click of a button.

First, I tried having the image array and text array seperate and use **Int(arc4random_uniform())** to randomly pick the elements from the array to display. It worked, BUT in doing so I need to make sure the image and its associated text are in the same position within their own array and I thought there must be better ways to structure the data by combining them into a multidimensional array or a dictionary. I end up using a dictionary, but got stuck don't know how to get the image and text to display.

See in the code below **//THIS IS THE BIT I GOT STUCK AT**. I don't know how to retrieve the image and its text from the dictionary.

I am not sure if it's ok to put the myImage and myText var in the dictionary and it seems a bit tedious to keep repeating '**myImage**', '**myText**' for each set as well.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myText:  = UILabel()

var randomSet = [[myImage:"1-image", myText:"text for 1"], [myImage:"2-image", myText:"text for 2"], [myImage:"3-image", myText:"text for 3"], [myImage:"4-image", myText:"text for 4"], [myImage:"5-image", myText:"text for 5"]]

func randomiseSet (){
        let randomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
        //THIS IS THE BIT I GOT STUCK AT
        myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber])
        myText.text = randomSet[randomNumber]
        //END
    }

@IBAction func showRandomSet(_ sender: UIButton) {
        randomiseSet()
    }
```

I also tried instead of using myImage.image = .... myText.text = ....

```swift
return randomSet[[randomNumber]]
```

Both didn't work and showed 'Build Failed'

I have also investigated using CoreData but I'm a noob and that opens another can of worm for me regarding binary data for images vs using URL due to image size etc.

Any suggestion on what's the best way to fix the above is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line `myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber])` is wrong because `randomSet[randomNumber]` returns `[String:String]`, not `String`. What you instead need to do is `randomSet[randomNumber]["myImage"]`, which will return the string you want to initialize the `UIImage`.

Also note: your dictionary's keys should be `String`s in this case. Unless `myImage` and `myText` are declared as `String`s elsewhere, your dictionary is set up incorrectly. Try changing your `randomSet` to `[["myImage":"1-image", "myText":"text for 1"], ["myImage":"2-image", "myText":"text for 2"], ["myImage":"3-image", "myText":"text for 3"], ["myImage":"4-image", "myText":"text for 4"], ["myImage":"5-image", "myText":"text for 5"]]`

So, implementing the changes, your code should look something like this:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
//Note this change from `@IBOutlet weak var myText:  = UILabel()`, which is incorrect
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UILabel!

var randomSet: [[String:String]] = [["myImage":"1-image", "myText":"text for 1"], ["myImage":"2-image", "myText":"text for 2"], ["myImage":"3-image", "myText":"text for 3"], ["myImage":"4-image", "myText":"text for 4"], ["myImage":"5-image", "myText":"text for 5"]]

func randomiseSet (){
    let randomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
    myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber]["myImage"]!)
    myText.text = randomSet[randomNumber]
}

@IBAction func showRandomSet(_ sender: UIButton) {
    randomiseSet()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I set up the dictionary incorrectly. After reading https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary, I start to think that I shouldn't use a dictionary but a 2-D array instead. I tried your suggestion but there're error messages next to the myImage.image = ... and myText.text = ... lines. I tried myText.text = randomSet[randomNumber]["myText"] which stopped its error message and commented out the myImage.image = ... with the error message, click play to build it but it didnt' work. So I tried the below (next message in the post)...

Comment: I would use an array of dictionaries like you were using. 2D arrays aren't good for storing key/value pairs. They're better for representing things like grids (think like a chess board).

Comment: Amending my own original question instead, adding the part I tried with a 2-D array. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error on the `myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber]["myImage"])` line? I imagine there is some optional handling we need to do. We may need to change it to `myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber]["myImage"]!)`

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much for the info!

Comment: Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'  Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'  Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Comment: It should give you a solution by clicking the white circle within the red circle. But you need to handle the optionals. Changing to this `myImage.image = UIImage(named: randomSet[randomNumber]["myImage"]!)` should fix it.

Comment: I added the ! at the end of myImage.image line, the error messages disappeared but once it's in build it crashes then show a white screen...

Comment: What is the runtime error? I imagine your image is incorrectly named.

Comment: The runtime error is ...terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException... I named the images pretty much the same as I described, and they have the same names as the files in the Assets.xcassets folder.

Comment: What is the error printing to the console? That is what will tell us what the issue is.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help and time. Fixed now. Sorry, I've changed the name of the image outlet from randomImage to myImage, not knowing that even when I changed all the references to it in the code, when I right click on the image it's still showing 'randomImage' as the outlet name. The bit in the console mentioned about 'randomImage' (so I changed it back)... Sorry about my newbie-ness. Definitely learnt a lot from asking.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting this answer as correct?

Comment: Cool, done. I clicked the up arrow a few times but says I need more than 15 reputations. Didn't notice there's a tick underneath it. 

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I can use a .plist file to keep the properties in the dictionary organised rather than listing them all out in code like that...